# Kernelbase.pdb error when trying to recursively delete an entire binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

Below is a chunk of my code that is causing the problem

```
void delete_tree(tree_node* root){
    if (root) {
        delete_tree(root->left);
        delete_tree(root->right);
        if (root) {
            delete root;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with this code is that I get random exceptions regarding "Kernelbase.pdb not loaded" in Visual Studio 22.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8BA6A1665 (KernelBase.dll) in HW3.exe: 0x40010005: Control-C.
```

The exception does not pop up at specific lines but at any point in the function. This function is only reached when I press ctrl+c to stop a loop that only ends when I stop it using ctrl + c. It works when I enter ctrl + z and press enter. What could be the solution considering I need to use ctrl + c?

I have tried turning on MS symbols under Tools/Options/Debugging but that stops the code from running. The expectation is that the program deletes all nodes of the tree and returns back to the main. I have also tried restarting my computer but to no avail

Comment: Switch the "Stack Frame" combobox on the Debug toolbar to your code and inspect the variables.

Comment: I expect the problem is you have corrupted the heap or your tree in some other part of your code.

Comment: `"Kernelbase.pdb not loaded"` Please note that a missing pdb is not the cause of your problem. Having the `pdb` files will let you debug deep inside your OS and let you understand what your OS is doing and perhaps you could fix or at least better understand a windows bug. In most instances for an application developer you will not need or want to debug your OS so not having the pdb is not a real limitation or issue. You could use the Microsoft Symbol server to check and download the missing dlls but for me this causes a delay at the start of a debug session so I disable it.